# __new__ confusion regarding instantiation

Tags: python, instantiation

Im trying to get my head around how `__new__` works and currently I just cant figure it out.

According to [this blog post explaining the `__new__` method](http://howto.lintel.in/python-__new__-magic-method-explained/), to construct my instance I do this: `super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`

However, whenever I direct my `__new__` to instantiate from another class it doesn't seem to take in the arguments, or if I do `Bar.__new__(cls)` it doesn't seem to accept this at all. Thoroughly confused.

My code:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       self.c = c

    def hello(self):
        print("HelloBar")

class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return Bar.__new__(cls) # Have tried doing stuff like 
                                # super().__new__(bar) as well, no success

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

i = Foo(2,3,4)
```

I'm trying to point to an instance of the class `Bar`, how do I do this?

Comment: So what is the goal here, to return a new instance of `Bar()` instead? Why bother with having a `__init__` method on `Foo()` then?

Comment: It was more of trying to understand just how `__new__` works and objects in python work as a whole. I've learnt basic theory behind classes but am looking at projects to see how they implement it, the particular one I was looking at was this [one](https://codingsec.net/2016/05/decoding-ip-layer-python/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `Bar()` directly; `Bar()` is a different class altogether, `Foo.__new__` doesn't have to deal with how that class is implemented.

You *do* have to pass along the arguments your `Foo(...)` call were passed, if you want to be able to create a `Bar()` instance:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return Bar(*args, **kwargs)
```

You only need to use `super().__new__()` inside `Foo.__new__`, because there you have overridden the `object.__new__` method but still need to access it to create the actual instance.

You can still call `Bar.__new__(Bar, *args, **kwargs)` or `object.__new__(Bar, *args, **kwargs)`, but then you are bypassing the `Bar.__init__` method. That's because `ClassObject(...)` is translated to `type(ClassObject).__call__(ClassObject, ...)`, and it is the job of that `__call__()` method to then invoke `__new__`, followed by `__init__` only if `__new__` produced an instance of `ClassObject`. Expressed in Python code, it looks a bit like this:

```
def __call__(type_, cls, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(instance, cls):
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return instance
```

If `Foo.__new__()` returns an instance of `Bar`, then `isinstance(instace, Foo)` is false and the `type(Foo).__call__()` implementation will not call the `__init__` method on that object. By calling `Bar()` you make sure that `type(Bar).__call__()` has taken care of the job of calling `Bar.__init__()`.